# Custom taxonomy page template not found

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I list all posts from a custom taxonomy category into a custom template? Below is the code.

So I`ve created a custom taxonomy like this:

```
register_taxonomy('miniblog_category', 'post', array(
    // Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
    'hierarchical' => true,
    // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'MiniBlog Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'MiniBlog Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search MiniBlog Categories' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All MiniBlog Categories' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent MiniBlog Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent MiniBlog Category:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit MiniBlog Category' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update MiniBlog Category' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New MiniBlog Category' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New MiniBlog Category Name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'MiniBlog Categories' ),
    ),
    // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
    'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'miniblog', 
      'with_front' => false, 
    ),
  ));
```

After that I also created a custom widgets that is displayed on the author`s page (right sidebar). This widget displays all current author's categories with the post numbers (the code below):

```
...
$current_author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
        $categories_by_post_no = array();
        foreach (get_terms('miniblog_category') as $mbc) {
            // metadata term( blogger_id )
            $taxonomy_blogger_id = get_term_meta($mbc->term_id, 'blogger_id', true) ;
            if ($taxonomy_blogger_id == $current_author_id) {
                $arg_author_posts = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'post_status' => 'published',
                    'miniblog_category' => $mbc->slug,
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                );
                $term_link = get_term_link($mbc->term_id, $mbc->slug);
                $categories_by_post_no[] = array(
                    'name' => $mbc->name, 
                    'post_count' => count( get_posts( $arg_author_posts ) ),
                    'term_link' => get_term_link($mbc),
                );
            }
        }
        if (! empty($categories_by_post_no) ) {
            echo '<ul class="menu">';
            foreach ($categories_by_post_no as $cbpn) {
                echo "<li><a href='" . $cbpn['term_link'] . "'>$cbpn[name] ($cbpn[post_count])<a/></li>";
            };
            echo'</ul>';
        } else {
            echo '<span>No articles!</span>';
        }
...
```

In my case the links ($cbpn['term_link']) are like this:
 - miniblog/culture
 - miniblog/nature
 - miniblog/south-america
...
but when I click on those links I received a 404 not found error.
I tried to create in the theme folder files like this (taxonomy-miniblog.php, taxonomy-miniblog-category.php) but it doesn't work. Do I have to create files for each category, e.g. taxonomy-miniblog-culture.php, taxonomy-miniblog-nature.php ...(no way!!)?

Comment: Have you flushed your permalinks since adding the taxonomy? Also have you registered the taxonomy on the init hook or just thrown it into your functions.php?

Comment: You tried taxonomy-miniblog-category but didn't try taxonomy-miniblog_category.php? Please try it!

Comment: @Natahan: I forgot this! It works now (default archive template is loaded)! What is the correct way to do the permalinks flush?

Comment: @Fatih: this is the correct filename. Thanks!